# ObservableCollection not loading data correctly

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

Just a bit of background of what I am trying to do, I have a syncfusion `listview` that updates the data from the database with a REST api call. I get weekly data. There is another button on the view that should updates the list with monthly data.

For weekly, I have 1 record in the db and list gets populated with data. After clicking on the "view all" button, the db gives the data and list receives 13 records but the view update just one of it. Looks like the list has limited to show just one. Here is the code:

```
 private ObservableCollection<TransactionInformationDto> listItems;


    public ObservableCollection<TransactionChartData> ChartData { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<TransactionInformationDto> TransactionList
    {
        get { return listItems; }
        set { listItems = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TransactionList)); }

    }

    public ICommand GetTransactions => new Command(async () =>
    {
         IsBusy = true;
         TransactionList.Clear();
         var data = await GetAllTransactions();
          foreach(var item in data)
          {
              TransactionList.Add(item);
          }
         IsBusy = false;
    });

    public Command<object> ItemTappedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemTappedCommand ?? (this.itemTappedCommand = new Command<object>(ShowTransactionInformation));
        }
    }

    private void ShowTransactionInformation(object item)
    {
        var list = item as Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.ItemTappedEventArgs;
        var transaction = (TransactionInformationDto)list.ItemData;
        Navigation.PushAsync(new TransactionInfoPage(transaction));
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public DashboardPageViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        LoadTransactionDetails();
        
        Navigation = navigation;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public double TotalBalance
    {
        get
        {
            return totalBalance;
        }
        set
        {
            this.totalBalance = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public INavigation Navigation { get; }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    private async Task<ObservableCollection<TransactionInformationDto>> GetAllTransactions()
    {      
           var retrievalInformation = await App.Database.GetUserRetrievalInformation();
            return new ObservableCollection<TransactionInformationDto>(await DependencyService.Get<IGetInformation>().GetAllUserTransactions(retrievalInformation));
    }

    private void LoadTransactionDetails()
    {
        var userTransactions = new List<TransactionInformationDto>();
        Task.Run(async () => {
            var retrievalInformation = await App.Database.GetUserRetrievalInformation();
            var userBalance = await DependencyService.Get<IGetInformation>().GetUserBalanceInformation(retrievalInformation);
            TotalBalance = userBalance.CurrentBalance;
            userTransactions = await DependencyService.Get<IGetInformation>().GetTransactionData(retrievalInformation);
        });

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        WeekData(userTransactions);
    }

    private void WeekData(List<TransactionInformationDto> transactionInformation)
    {
        TransactionList = new ObservableCollection<TransactionInformationDto>();
        var data = new ObservableCollection<TransactionInformationDto>(transactionInformation.OrderByDescending(x =>x.TimeStamp));
        foreach(var item in data)
        {
            TransactionList.Add(item);
        }
        days = new string[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
        ChartData = new ObservableCollection<TransactionChartData>();
        UpdateChartData(days);
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">

                    <Label Margin="16,26,16,16"
                           Text="TRANSACTIONS"
                           TextColor="{StaticResource Gray-800}"
                           FontSize="12"
                           LineHeight="{OnPlatform Android=1.5, Default=-1}" 
                           HorizontalOptions="Start" />

                    <buttons:SfButton Margin="11,26,11,16"
                                      BorderWidth="0"
                                      TextColor="{StaticResource Gray-600}"
                                      BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Transparent}"
                                      WidthRequest="72"
                                      HeightRequest="18"
                                      Command="{Binding GetTransactions}"
                                      CornerRadius="4"
                                      HorizontalOptions="End">
                        <Label Text="VIEW ALL"
                               TextColor="{DynamicResource Link}"
                               FontSize="12"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                               LineHeight="{OnPlatform Android=1.5, Default=-1}"
                                />
                    </buttons:SfButton>

                </Grid>

                <listView:SfListView Grid.Row="2" 
                                     x:Name="_transactionList"
                                     IsScrollBarVisible="False"
                                     ItemSpacing="0"
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding TransactionList}"
                                     SelectionBackgroundColor="{StaticResource TappedBackgroundColor}"
                                     TapCommand="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}"
                                     AutoFitMode="Height"
                                     BackgroundColor="White">
                    <listView:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>   
                                
                                 <!--Profile pic-->
                                <border:SfBorder Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                                 Margin="16"
                                                 WidthRequest="40"
                                                 HeightRequest="40"
                                                 CornerRadius="20"
                                                 BorderWidth="0"
                                                 VerticalOptions="Center">
                                    <Image Aspect="Fill"
                                           Source="receipt">
                                    </Image>
                                </border:SfBorder>

                                <!-- Name -->
                                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                       Margin="0,15,0,4"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                       Text="{Binding ReceiverName}"
                                       LineHeight="{OnPlatform Android=1.5, Default=-1}" />

                                <!-- Transaction Title -->
                                <Label Grid.Row="1"
                                       Grid.Column="1"
                                       Margin="0,0,0,16"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                       Text="{Binding TransactionMessage}"
                                       TextColor="{StaticResource Gray-700}"
                                       FontSize="12"
                                       LineHeight="{OnPlatform Android=1.5, Default=-1}" />

                                <!-- Amount -->
                                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                       Margin="0,16,16,4"
                                       HorizontalOptions="End"
                                       TextColor="{Binding IsReceived, Converter={x:StaticResource BooleanToColorConverter}, ConverterParameter=5}"
                                       LineHeight="{OnPlatform Android=1.5, Default=-1}">
                                    <Label.FormattedText>
                                        <FormattedString>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding IsReceived, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToStringConverter}, ConverterParameter=2}" />
                                            <Span Text=" $" />
                                            <Span Text="{Binding TransactionAmount}" />
                                        </FormattedString>
                                    </Label.FormattedText>
                                </Label>

                                <!-- Date -->
                                <Label Grid.Row="1"
                                       Grid.Column="1"
                                       Margin="0,0,16,16"
                                       HorizontalOptions="End"
                                       Text="{Binding TimeStamp, StringFormat='{}{0:dd MMM yyyy}'}"
                                       TextColor="{StaticResource Gray-700}"
                                       FontSize="12"
                                       LineHeight="{OnPlatform Android=1.5, Default=-1}" />

                                <!-- Seperator -->
                                <BoxView Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyle}" />

                            </Grid>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </listView:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                </listView:SfListView>
                <controls:Popup Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy}" LoadingMessage="Loading the list.." />
            </Grid>`
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you **positive** that `TransactionList` contains 13 items?

Comment: yes, I have been debugging it. LoadTransactionDetails will put 1 item in the list. Then GetAllTransactions will put 13 items in the list. While using the Hot Reload if I save the xaml it updates the UI with 13 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. don't ever use Thread.Sleep(). It blocks the UI (UI hangs / doesn't respond) if it's run on the UI Thread.

1.1. Trying to fix something by adding Thread.Sleep() and Task.Delay() is a step more towards hell. Don't enter this path!

2. You don't need to use ObservableCollection everywhere. If you don't need Observability, use IList or IEnumerable or an array.
3. Task.Run() crates a new thread. You usually don't need this. + You have issues in databinding, because you need to ensure the binding is executed on the UI thread, to be able to update the UI component.
4. Don't load data in the constructor. Trigger the loading in and lifecycle event like PageAppearing() (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle)

**Updated code**

```
private ObservableCollection<TransactionInformationDto> listItems;


public ObservableCollection<TransactionChartData> ChartData { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<TransactionInformationDto> TransactionList
{
    get { return listItems; }
    set { listItems = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TransactionList)); }

}

public ICommand GetTransactions => new Command(async () =>
{
     IsBusy = true;
     TransactionList.Clear();
     var data = await GetAllTransactions();
     TransactionList = new ObservableCollection<TransactionInformationDto>(data);
     IsBusy = false;
});

public Command<object> ItemTappedCommand
{
    get
    {
        return this.itemTappedCommand ?? (this.itemTappedCommand = new Command<object>(ShowTransactionInformation));
    }
}

private void ShowTransactionInformation(object item)
{
    var list = item as Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.ItemTappedEventArgs;
    var transaction = (TransactionInformationDto)list.ItemData;
    Navigation.PushAsync(new TransactionInfoPage(transaction));
}
#endregion

#region Constructor
public DashboardPageViewModel(INavigation navigation)
{
    // LoadTransactionDetails(); // <<< see 4.
    
    Navigation = navigation;
}

#endregion

#region Properties

public double TotalBalance
{
    get
    {
        return totalBalance;
    }
    set
    {
        this.totalBalance = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public INavigation Navigation { get; }
#endregion

#region Methods
private async Task<IEnumerable<TransactionInformationDto>> GetAllTransactions() // see 2.
{      
       var retrievalInformation = await App.Database.GetUserRetrievalInformation();
       return await DependencyService.Get<IGetInformation>().GetAllUserTransactions(retrievalInformation);
}

private async Task LoadTransactionDetails()
{
    var userTransactions = new List<TransactionInformationDto>();  
    // see 3.
    var retrievalInformation = await App.Database.GetUserRetrievalInformation();
    var userBalance = await DependencyService.Get<IGetInformation>().GetUserBalanceInformation(retrievalInformation);
    TotalBalance = userBalance.CurrentBalance;
    userTransactions = await DependencyService.Get<IGetInformation>().GetTransactionData(retrievalInformation);
    // see. 1. & 1.1.
    WeekData(userTransactions);
}

private void WeekData(List<TransactionInformationDto> transactionInformation)
{
    TransactionList = new ObservableCollection<TransactionInformationDto>(transactionInformation.OrderByDescending(x =>x.TimeStamp));
    days = new string[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
    ChartData = new ObservableCollection<TransactionChartData>();
    UpdateChartData(days);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sven, I will try it and let you know. I am sure the way I was doing was bit hacky but it was the only way working.

Comment: Thanks alot Sven, I solved the issue. It was due to 2 things. The first was the Task.Run() which was creating another thread and not updating the UI. The second was the syncfusion library databinding. I changed it to the normal ListView and it works. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The Task.Run method will run on a separate thread that tries to update the UI. The layout will be updated when adding the items in the main thread. UI threads get interrupted which restricts the layouts in the application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/ios-ui/ui-thread#background-thread-example
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/96756